# Python Big-Endian Conversion for .bin file

Tags: python, binary, endianness

I am trying to convert Matlab code to Python for binary files. Forgive me l am new to this language.

**Matlab:**

```
fileID = fopen('file_name.bin','r');
DC = fread(fileID,'single','b');
```

**Python:**

```
import numpy as np
with open('Duty_Cycle.bin','rb') as fid:
    data_array = np.fromfile(fid, np.float32, dtype = '>u4')
print(data_array)
```

**Result:**

```
TypeError: argument for fromfile() given by name ('dtype') and position (2)
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature for `fromfile` is

```
fromfile(file, dtype=float, count=-1, sep='', offset=0)
```

By specifying both the second positional argument `np.float32` and the keyword argument `dtype='>u4'`, you gave the same parameter twice, and thus the error. The documentation isn't terribly clear, but you can just use the string specification to specify both the type and endianness.

```
data_array = np.fromfile(fid, dtype='>u4')
```

Comment: How to identify multiple columns in a row? if my format is like first 4 bytes for an integer value next 2 bytes for next integer value  like this if it has 10 columns.

Comment: @sjd - that's a good question. I couldn't find a good way to do that. A numpy array can only have 1 type and it assumes the binary data is 1 type. You could use the `struct` module to unpack into a list of ints and then pack into an io.BytesIO buffer (or a different file on disk) using a single type uint32.

Comment: -Right, Thanks, I could do something like below 
`with open(mybinfile, 'rb') as file:
        while True:
            firstcol = file.read(4)
            if not firstcol: break
            col1 = int.from_bytes(firstcol, byteorder='big')
            col2 = int.from_bytes(file.read(4), byteorder='big')
            col3 = int.from_bytes(file.read(2), byteorder='big')`

Comment: works if we know the length of bytes for each column